# Can we create a Skype bot which multiple clients can use on their Sype for Business accounts?

Tags: skype, chatbot, skype-for-business, skype-bots

We are a B2B serving company and want to create a Chat Bot. A good portion of our clients use Skype for Business. Can we create such a Chat Bot?

Comment: Team request your help #botframework

Comment: Just as a side node here, as Skype for Business supports XMPP, you might wish to build a XMPP Chat boot, which allows that this one could be used for companies as well who do not use Skype but use an XMPP chat environment...